# Best approach to extract table data to process data

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

I want to extract the data from DB using python and want to make some modifications to it. I can achieve it by writing the data into CSV and process on it, but modifications requires data from another tables as well. I don't want to extract data from all the table and create many CSV files. Please suggest any alternative. Should I use pandas dataframes?

Comment: Have you consider using `pd.read_sql`?

Comment: Pandas dataframes are good for this. You can pull all of your database queries with pandas.read_sql, which gives you a dataframe for each pull, and then do whatever modification/combination of them you want in the python script with pandas commands.

Comment: @JacobH Thanks for the information. I am using pandas library and its working like charm.